# Rails RuntimeError: Invalid option key:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, runtime-error

Hey folks I built an app with rails-api 5.0.6 and appear to be getting the same error on all my controller tests: (rails test)

```
RuntimeError: Invalid option key: raise_on_unfiltered_parameters=
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

reporter.rb:70:in `method': undefined method `test_should_create_me
mbership' for class `Minitest::Result' (NameError)
```

Some of the controllers were built with scaffold.  Any thoughts as to what would be causing this?  Thanks.

Comment: So it appears the setup method isn't loading any of the fixtures either.  I'm not sure what is going on.  I've built a new app from scratch and none of the tests work on that either.  I believe the issue is with rails 5.

Comment: Oh, it might have something to do with token auth not being setup.